# Using scanner to put file contents into an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to take the contents of a file into an array. The file contents are positive and negative integers.

This is what I did to find how big I should make the array. inFile is my scanner. I am able to print the contents of inFile, but they won't go into the array. I just get null values.

```
    int arrayLength = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNextInt()){
        inFile.nextInt();
        arrayLength++;
    }
```

This is what I tried to do to get the file contents into the array.

```
    int[] nums = new int[arrayLength]; //make array according to arrayLength
    inFile.reset();
    //fill array with values from file
    for (int n = 0; n > arrayLength; n++) {
        nums[n] = inFile.nextInt();
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `nextInt()` in the first loop you're "moving" a virtual cursor over your stream and you cannot go back again.

Let's say you have an input like:

```
17
-15
13
```

Then, when you call `nextInt()` for the first time, your cursor move from 17 to -15. So calling `nextInt()` at each loop will necessarily cause to have null values in the second loop.

You should try to use [dynamic arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) or maybe a list (which don't have a fixed size)

Comment: I thought that's what the Scanner.reset() method fixed. Shouldn't the cursor go back to the beginning?

Comment: Look at the [javadoc for scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset--), it only resets the delimeter, locale and radix.